# Pesquisa no listview não mostra o item correspondente

Tags: android, listview, algoritmo-de-busca

No listview quando pesquiso um item ele mostra o nome correspondente certo, mas quando clico para reproduzir ele toca outro item ao invés do item buscado.

### MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ArrayList<memes> item;
    ArrayAdapter<memes> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.memes_main);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        item = new ArrayList<>();
        item.add(new memes("Gemidão", R.raw.gemidaoremix));
        item.add(new memes("Nunca nem vi", R.raw.nuncanemvi));
        item.add(new memes("Caga", R.raw.caga));
        item.add(new memes("Cagado de fome", R.raw.cagado));
        item.add(new memes("Cala Boca", R.raw.calaboca));
        item.add(new memes("Canal", R.raw.canal));
        item.add(new memes("Capeta", R.raw.capeta));

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //play audio
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);
            }
        });

    }

 //aqui é onde faço a logica do searchview
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu){
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.busca, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.sv);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {

        mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, item.get(songIndex).getResId());

        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }

    }
```

adapter

### memes.class ##

```
public class memes{

private String nome;
private int resID;

memes(String nome, int resID){

    this.nome = nome;
    this.resID = resID;
}

public String getNome(){
    return nome;
}

int getResId(){
    return resID;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return nome;
}

}
```

Comment: Isso só acontece quando a lista apresenta parte das musicas ou acontece também quando a lista apresenta a totalidade delas?

Comment: @ramaral  acontece quando a busca é feita, sem busca os áudios tocam como deveriam

Answer (score 0):

A razão disso acontecer é por estar a usar a posição do item clicado como índice para obter a música no array `resID`.

A correspondência entre a posição e o índice só é correcta quando `lstEstados_Encontrados` tem o mesmo número de itens que `resID`.

Suponha que ao fazer a procura `lstEstados_Encontrados` fica assim:

```
NHA
Rolezeira
```

ao clicar em `Rolezeira` o valor obtida para a posição é `1`. Quando usa esse valor no array `resID` vai obter o valor correspondente ao índice 1, que é `R.raw.eso`.

Em vez de ter um array para os nomes e outro para os *resID* crie uma classe que contenha esses dois valores:

```
public class Content{

    private String nome;
    private int resID;

    public Content(String nome, int resID){

        this.nome = nome;
        this.resID = resID;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    public int getResId(){
        return resID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Use essa classe como item das listas `listContent` e `lstEstados_Encontrados`:

```
private ArrayList<Content> listContent = new ArrayList<Content>();
private ArrayList<Content> lstEstados_Encontrados = new ArrayList<Content>();
```

Comment: o que eu faço nesse caso? algumas linhas ficaram vermelhas acho que fiz algo errado nas referencias   http://prntscr.com/gm0ei6

print da sons.class
http://prntscr.com/gm0gw2

Comment: alguma coisa sim.
eu fiz as duas referencias 
`private ArrayList<sons> listContent = new ArrayList<sons>();
private ArrayList<sons> lstEstados_Encontrados = new ArrayList<sons>();`
tentei com content tbm

Comment: Essa "alguma coisa" parece-me pouco, já que lhe dei toda a informação para você poder fazer tudo. Tem de preencher o ArrayList `listContent` com objectos do tipo `Content`: `listContent.add(new Content("NHA", R.raw.ne));`, faça isto para cada um dos sons. Os arrays `listContent`e `resID` não são mais necessários. Pode alterar o nome da classe Content mas não altere o seu conteúdo. Altere o restante código para deixar de usar os referidos Array e passar a usar ArrayList. Não me peça para fazer todo o código por si :)

Comment: vc fiz como pediu, mas continuo com o msm problema, vc poderia dar uma olhada no codigo?

Comment: Deve usar o ArrayList que foi filtrado para obter a musica a tocar.

Comment: consegui ja vlw