# Remover acentuação na busca usando searchview android

Tags: java, android

Gostaria que quando fosse buscado em meu listview `João` fosse exibido `João, Joao, joão, joao`.

Estou usando um searchview, li algo sobre Normalizer mas n entendi muito bem.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.busca, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.sv);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.busca, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.sv);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        //Irá tirar não só acentuações mas também qualquer caractere fora de ASCII
        String texto;
             texto = Normalizer.normalize(query, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");

        //seu código

            return false;
        }

       //se for pra passar o texto já modificado para o arrayAdapter, vc faz:
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
             String texto;
             texto = Normalizer.normalize(newText, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");

            arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(texto);
            return true;
        }
    });

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Comment: `Desculpa sou iniciante ainda mas oq eu coloco no lugar de `searchT` esta vermelho e `texto` não esta sendo usada

Comment: Eu corrigi, olha dnv, no lugar do searchT vc coloca a query

Comment: Ali vc coloca o texto q quer q seja modificado

Comment: Deu erro pq copiei d um projeto aq e acabei esquecendo d mudar essa parte antes d colocar aqui kkkk, dscp aí

Comment: @Welyson se caso a resposta resolveu seu problema, a marque como aceita para que outras que tiverem o mesmo problema também consigam resolve-lo

Comment: ok, mas estou com um problema o texto esta passando por adapter de uma arraylist de objetos, e n consigo passar pra la td q eu coloco da "nunca usada"

Comment: poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @Welyson cara, eu n entendi muito bem sua pergunta, acho melhor abrir outra pergunta com parte do código, fica melhor para o entendimento

Comment: @Welyson n, calmaí, vc fala no  onQueryTextChange?

Comment: sim `String como eu passo meu texto aqui;
                aqui= Normalizer.normalize(query, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");`

eu tento passar mas n vai

Comment: olha esse é meu codigo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237899/pesquisa-no-listview-n%C3%A3o-mostra-o-item-correspondente

Comment: @Welyson ri mt agr por causa dos memes, mas voltando ao caso, vc quer passar para o arraylist o seu texto sem acentos, certo?

Comment: Eu vou modificar a resposta, olha lá

Comment: @Welyson veja se é isso q vc quer

Comment: infelizmente nao funcionou, mas vc é um cara bem legal vou desistir dessa batalha e partir para tentativa de criação de um sistema de favoritos vlw caso queira me ajudar

Comment: @Welyson sad...

Answer (score 0):

O código da resposta anterior funciona perfeitamente, porém no caso em questão é preciso converter tanto essa String de passagem newText como a String que está dentro do Adapter com a qual você vai comparar, no meu caso ficou assim:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_only_menu, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.pesquisa_button);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);                                       //Troca o botão de buscar para confirmar, já que a busca é em tempo real então não faz muito sentido ter o botão "pesquisar"

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Convertendo o texto de entrada para caracteres equivalentes sem acentuação, ç etc
                String texto;
                texto = Normalizer.normalize(newText, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
                //Chamando o filter
                clienteAdapter.getFilter().filter(texto);
                return false;
            }
        });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }
```

E dentro do Adapter:

```
@Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<ClienteEntity> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                filteredList.addAll(clientesListaFull);                                             //Quando não há nada digitado na pesquisa, mostramos a lista completa (padrão).
            }else{
                //Trasforma a CharSequence em uma String, coloca tudo minúsculo e remove espaços.
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for(ClienteEntity cliente : clientesListaFull){                                     //Percorre cliente por cliente da lista de clientes.
                    String nomeNoASCII;
                    nomeNoASCII = Normalizer.normalize(cliente.getName(), Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                            .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
                    if(nomeNoASCII.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){                          //Se a CharSequence digitada estiver contida no cliente.getName, adicionamos esse cliente ao resultado da busca.
                        filteredList.add(cliente);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }
```